# Maven and working with legacy app

Tags: maven-3

In order to work with a legacy app framework I need to split a webapp project into 2.  1 jar needs to have the java class files, the other will have all the web stuff like jsps, css, et. al..  How can I do this with on maven-3 pom?

Comment: Do you need the separated jar with the class files for other projects ?

Comment: It is really for deployment.  The class files go in one place and the jsps go in another.

Answer (score 3):

For this purpose you can use the configuration of the [maven-war-plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-war-plugin/war-mojo.html#archiveClasses). This will create a separate jar file which contains the .class files...

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
    <configuration>
      <attachClasses>true</attachClasses>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

like xyz-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT-classes.jar which can be used as a separated dependency (you have to use the supplemental classifier).

If the war artifact should not contain any classes, you can achieve this by adding the [packagingExcludes](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-war-plugin/war-mojo.html#packagingExcludes) configuration.

```
      <packagingExcludes>WEB-INF/classes/**</packagingExcludes>
```