# Maven not honoring excludes

Tags: maven-3

We have this in our pom

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.2</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>assembly</id>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>jar</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <excludes>
                            <exclude>app/**</exclude>
                            <exclude>WEB-INF/**</exclude>
                        </excludes>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
                <execution>
                    <id>assembly-web</id>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>jar</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <classifier>web</classifier>
                        <includes>
                            <include>app/**</include>
                            <include>WEB-INF/**</include>
                        </includes>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```

When I open the xxx-web.jar it looks as expected, but when I look at xxx.jar it includes everything/didn't exclude anything.  If I were to add a classified to the 1st plugin (the one with the excludes) then it works properly???

I want this to work in such a way that the xxx.jar has all the class and property files and the xxx-web only has the jsp/css files.

Comment: Why are you using the jar plugin instead of the war-plugin ?

Comment: It really isn't a web app, there is now web.xml and there won't be one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at 7.1.6 in this maven [document](http://www.sonatype.com/books/mvnref-book/reference/_configuring_maven_plugins.html).  Basically you need to bind to the default goal of "default-jar".

HTH

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this: [Maven and working with legacy app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9415453/maven-and-working-with-legacy-app) there you will find the complete solution for your problem.

Comment: Well this isn't a web app the project doesn't have an xml, I guess you can look at the jsps and css files as just plain text files.

Answer (score 0):

You're telling maven to execute twice with each `<execution>` command. Try putting the includes and excludes under the same execution.

Comment: that will make 1 jar file, I want 2.  1 with the class files and the other with the jsps, css, etc.